# Load an action which is in an url with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using WP fvorite post.
The action to make as favorite is in the url :
http://mywebsite.com/?wpfpaction=add&postid=350

So when I click in a button with this url, it make it as favorite.

I want to make it as favorite when I open the post directly. Each time I open a post, I want to make it as favorite. Is there a way to load the url when I open the post but I don't want to load the page one more time but just load the action.

I tried this :

```
$( "#result" ).load( "/?wpfpaction=add&postid=350" );
```

and

```
$( "#result" ).load( "htp://www.mywebsite.com/?wpfpaction=add&postid=350" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.load()` is used to load content into an element. And you need to send a ping/request to a url, don't need to use what is returned/responded. So, `$.post()` or `$.get()` the the solution for this.

```
$.get('', 'wpfpaction=add&postid=350');
```

Usage With the current post id -

```
$.get('', 'wpfpaction=add&postid=<?php the_ID(); ?>');
```

To dynamically add it from functions.php, you will need to hook on wp_footer

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpf_on_the_footer');
function wpf_on_the_footer()
{
    if( is_single () ) ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.get('', 'wpfpaction=add&postid=<?php the_ID(); ?>');
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: it's working great but I want to replace 350 by : <?php the_ID() ?> I don't know how to do that because It's php and JS

Comment: Check the updated answer.